# How to render a variable which is having a wysiwyg type format?

Tags: 7, forms

I am creating a variable in admin section that is of form type **#type = text_format** to get wysiwyg kind of editor. But having difficulty while displaying the field value in template file.
I am trying to print like below in template file:

```
print_r(variable_get('web_pagetext', ''));
```

But in frontend its showing like below:

```
Array ( [value] => text, text..
[format] => full_html )
```

How I can remove Array([value], [format]) and only text to get displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`check_markup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/7.x) for that:

```
$item = variable_get('web_pagetext', ['value' => '', 'format' => '']);
$formatted_text = check_markup($item['value'], $item['format');
```